# What is the proper pattern for handling async operations in an event handler?

Tags: .net, task

I'm absolutely down with the whole 'all the way down' philosophy of async programming.  However, there are many places in .Net where you just don't have any control over the calling signature.  Event handlers come to mind.  Event handlers have no return type (they're events, after all):

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(0).ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

If I use this pattern, I get flagged by the analyzer that I should observe the awaitable by using an await.  That's not an option in a handler.  So I tried this pattern:

```
protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(0).ConfigureAwait(false)).Wait();
}
```

And I'm told that waiting on a synchronous task can cause a deadlock.  There's a suggestion to use the 'JoinableTaskFactory.Run', but that's in a Visual Studio package and I don't what to bring in an additional package for something that should be a core method.

So what is the best practice for handling a long running task in an event handler?

Comment: Make handler async void, remove Task.Run (does nothing useful here, and actually in most really async code), and ensure exceptions are handled in some way by wrapping whole block into try catch and at least logging it or act in some way (show error in UI).

Comment: If you are the autor of event and have access to the code which raises the event - you can also make event async.